# Average temperature

Tags: average, means

I have some time series data that contains the temperature of the living room, the temperature of the kitchen and the temperature of the master room in a house. Those measurements are taken **every 10 minutes**.

I want to get the overall temperature of the entire house so I calculate the average temperature across all 3 rooms (let's call it $T_\text{avg}$).

But now instead of having measurements every 10 minutes I want to aggregate my data and **make it daily**, for this purpose I have been thinking about calulating the average of all $T_\text{avg}$ so that I get an average temperature per day.

My question is, would this be incorrect (taking the average of average values)? I have been told that in some cases this is correct but in others it is not.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might want to record the median value instead.  That will be a little be more resistant to outliers.

Comment: There is average and average ... how do you take it across the rooms ? just $(T_1+T_2+T_3)/3$, or avg. weighted by sq.m., or avg-weighted by occupancy times ? what meaning / use would you like to give to your daily mean ? if two rooms are almost at constant T during the day, while another room changes T widely how are you going to account for that ? etc.

Comment: What do you consider “incorrect”?

Comment: Just to clarify: 

1. I calculate the average temperature across all rooms like this:  Tavg=(T1+T2+T3)/3

2. The meaning I want to give to the daily mean is a measurement that reflects a global temperature in the house, I am not particularly interested in showing that X room had a lower/higher temperature at a specific point in time. 

3. What do you consider “incorrect”? : I want to know if the logic behind my approach is an accurate representation of what I mean by "daily mean", as I said, some posts indicate that calculating the mean of other means is inaccurate depending on the case.